# I renamed my column to include table name. Why can't I rename it anymore?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I managed to rename a column in SQL, to both the table name, and the intended column name, seperated by a dot. I used this statement:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Booking.MasterBookingID', 'Booking.BookingID'
```

This worked, the problem is though, that it should have been:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Booking.MasterBookingID', 'BookingID'
```

So instead of my **column** being named `BookingID`, it is now named `Booking.BookingID`. So i figure, ok, I just need to rename it again. And I go:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Booking.Booking.BookingID', 'BookingID'
```

But that doesn't work:

```
> No item by the name of 'Booking.Booking.BookingID' could be found in
> the current database 'BookingSystemTest', given that @itemtype was
> input as '(null)'.
```

So I try several other approaches:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Booking.BookingID', 'BookingID'
```

same error as before.

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Booking.BookingID', 'BookingID', 'COLUMN'
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Booking.Booking.BookingID', 'BookingID', 'COLUMN'
```

both gives error:

```
> [Error Code: 15248, SQL State: S1000]  Either the parameter @objname
> is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

So how can I successfully rename my column, now that I've blundered, and renamed it to something that SQL obviously does not like very much?

Comment: EXEC sp_rename '[Booking].[Booking.MasterBookingID]', 'BookingID', perhaps.

Comment: try to do `Booking.[Booking.BookingID] ` instead of Booking.Booking.BookingID should be working fine

Comment: ...the simplest things. Ofcourse that works. Thanks. I've never named anything with dots before, so I've never been aware of the annotation

Comment: btw @jarlh, your comment is completely right, as of my original post, where I had an error in my third code example. But as MasterBookingID is long gone, the correct syntax was `Booking.[Booking.BookingID]` and not `Booking.[Booking.MasterBookingID]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add [] to denote separation of table n Column names.

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Booking.[Booking.BookingID]', 'BookingID'
```

Comment: That is completely correct. I learned something new today! Thanks